# Minimize $A=\frac{1+2^{x+y}}{1+4^x}+\frac{1+2^{x+y}}{1+4^y}$

Tags: maxima-minima

For $a,b>0$. Minimize $$A=\frac{1+2^{x+y}}{1+4^x}+\frac{1+2^{x+y}}{1+4^y}$$

---

i think we let $2^x=a;2^y=b$

Hence $A=\frac{1+ab}{1+a^2}+\frac{1+ab}{1+b^2}$

We need pro $A\geq 2$(Wolfram Alpha) but $x,y$ is a very odd number and i can't find how to prove it $\geq2$

Comment: $$A=\frac{1+ab}{1+2a}+\frac{1+ab}{1+2b}$$ or $$A=\frac{1+ab}{1+a^2}+\frac{1+ab}{1+b^2}$$?

Comment: oh, if $A=\frac{1+ab}{1+a^2}+\frac{1+ab}{1+b^2}$ i know how to do it

Answer (score 3):

we have to prove that $$(1+ab)\left(\frac{1}{1+a^2}+\frac{1}{1+b^2}\right)\geq 2$$ and this is equivalent to $${\frac { \left( ab-1 \right)  \left( a-b \right) ^{2}}{ \left( {a}^{2}
+1 \right)  \left( {b}^{2}+1 \right) }}
\geq 0$$ this is right if $$ab\geq 1$$